# How to select first not disabled element from collection in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a lot of buttons which are rendered by ng-repeat, some of them are enabled, other are disabled, in protractor I want to select first enabled button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deeper investigation I've found that it's possible to filter array of all buttons by using filter function which returns array of elements which pass filter function.

```
var element = element.all(by.css('.someClass')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.isEnabled();
}).first();
```

where elem.isEnabled() will check whether element is enabled and filter function will return array of enabled buttons then first() will select first enabled button